# Looking for an inscribed quadrangle in a rectangle with minimal perimeter

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I thought up an other math problem, and hope you all will find it interesting.

Given is a rectangle ABCD. The points P on the line AB, Q on BC, R on CD and S on AD are inner points of the rectangle sides.

Inner points of a line are all points of this line except the end points.

Now it shall be determined for which positions of the points P, Q, R and S, the rectangle PQRS has the smallest circumference.

Thanks for all good answers

[image]

Comment: I have included the graphics into your text.

Comment: @Jonathan I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Circumference is referring to perimeter right?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea. You can give me a tip.

Comment: You made this problem but you don't know what "circumference" means in your question?

Comment: Can you have a quadrilateral inside a rectangle with 4 points each on 4 sides, with a perimeter less than 2 times diagonal of the original rectangle? If not, why?

Comment: I am talking about the inner reactangle. How must the point P, Q, R ad S must be chosen so that the inner rectangle has the smallest circumference. I have also to prove it mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Maximal surface gives a minimal perimeter, I think. So, S, P, Q, R should be placed in the middle of the rectangular sides.

Answer (score 0):

The rhombus connecting middle points of sides of rectangle. Follows from property of light with equal incidence/reflectance angles at $(P,Q,R,S)$, or, of minimum length/time by Fermat's principle.